# Output database tables with child table to PhpExcel

Tags: mysql, codeigniter, phpexcel

I have a one-to-many relationship table and currently my problem is what I'm having difficulties to format my excel file into the following format. The table below is just to illustrate the problem I'm having.

`+----+--------------+--------------+-------------+---------------+
| id | company_name | company_code | employee_id | employee_name |
+----+--------------+--------------+-------------+---------------+
|  1 | orange       |         0001 |           1 | John          |
|    |              |              |           2 | Tom           |
|    |              |              |           3 | Mary          |
|  2 | apple        |         0002 |           4 | Tim           |
|  3 | pear         |         0003 |           5 | Jane          |
|    |              |              |           6 | Paul          |
+----+--------------+--------------+-------------+---------------+`

For now the result that I'm getting is

`+----+--------------+--------------+-------------+---------------+
| id | company_name | company_code | employee_id | employee_name |
+----+--------------+--------------+-------------+---------------+
|  1 | orange       |         0001 |           1 | John          |
|  1 | orange       |         0001 |           2 | Tom           |
|  1 | orange       |         0001 |           3 | Mary          |
|  2 | apple        |         0002 |           4 | Tim           |
|  3 | pear         |         0003 |           5 | Jane          |
|  3 | pear         |         0003 |           6 | Paul          |
+----+--------------+--------------+-------------+---------------+`

Controller:

```
function _createExcel($query,$filename)
{
    $objPHPExcel = new PHPExcel();
    $objPHPExcel->getProperties()->setTitle("export")->setDescription("none");

    $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0);


    $fields = $query->list_fields();
    $col = 0;

    // bold for first row (heading)
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('1:1')->getFont()->setBold(true);

    // for headings
    foreach($fields as $field)
    {
        $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValueByColumnAndRow($col, 1, $field);
        $col++;
    }

    //print_r($query->result());

    // for data
    $row = 3;
    foreach($query->result() as $data)
    {
        $col = 0;
        foreach ($fields as $field)
        {
            $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValueByColumnAndRow($col, $row, $data->$field);
            $col++;
        }
        $row++;
    }

    $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0);
    $objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'Excel5');

    header('Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename="'.$filename.' - '.date('dMy').'.xls"');
    header('Cache-Control: max-age=0');
    $objWriter->save('php://output');
}

function generateExcelReport($reportType)
{
    switch ($reportType)
    {
        case "pc_bc":
        {
            $this->load->model('publicationClaim_model');
            $query = $this->publicationClaim_model->getPublicationClaimQuery('bookChapter');
            $filename = "Publication Claim - Book Chapter";
            $this->_createExcel($query,$filename);
            break;
        }
        default:
        {
            echo "error";
        }
    }
}
```

Model:

```
function getPublicationClaimQuery($claimType)
{
    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from('claim');
    $this->db->join('claim_evidence', 'claim.claim_id = claim_evidence.claim_id');
    $this->db->where('claim.claim_type', $claimType);
    $query = $this->db->get();

    return $query;
}
```

Comment: Does the $query return what you want?

Comment: Yes. Except that it has repeating rows like the second table with different values from the child table

Comment: IN which format you need data?

Comment: The first one shown.